# HTML Meter Element Star Rating Not Working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am working on a meter element that uses stars instead of a line to display the value.  The 5-star rating works fine in everything but Chrome and Edge.  For some reason, in Chrome and Edge, it is displaying 1 star for every 1/2 value.  So if the value is 4.6 then it is displaying 9.1 stars.  The issue does not appear in Firefox, Safari (desktop or mobile), mobile internet browser, or the Chrome mobile app.  I have been trying to fix this with no luck.  Does anyone know what might be causing this, or a fix for this issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/mik3mitchell/jk7s9x85/9/

```css
meter {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.ratingscore {
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj48dGV4dCBmb250LXNpemU9IjEwMCIgeT0iMC44ZW0iIG9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMyI+4piFPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==);
}

.ratingscore::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj48dGV4dCBmb250LXNpemU9IjEwMCIgeT0iMC44ZW0iIGZpbGw9ImdvbGQiPuKYhTwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=);
}

.ratingscore:-moz-meter-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDAgMTAwIj48dGV4dCBmb250LXNpemU9IjEwMCIgeT0iMC44ZW0iIGZpbGw9ImdvbGQiPuKYhTwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=);
}

.ratingscore::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<meter class="ratingscore" value="4.6" min="0" max="5"></meter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't set fixed sizes for elements and each browser can set them in other way. Try this solution and let me know if it helped you. Set dimension for each pseudo-elements as for parent.

```css
.ratingscore {
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: ...;
}

.ratingscore::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: ...;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
}

.ratingscore:-moz-meter-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: ...;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
}

.ratingscore::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
}
```